# How would you pass an observable with params as @Input?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, parameters, observable

The goal is to pass an http request from component 1 to component 2 and set its params on component 2.

This is my approach pseudo code:

**Component 1 HTML**

```
<app-component-2 [obs]="obs"></app-component-1>
```

**Component 1 TS**

```
export class Component1 {

   obs : Observable<any>;      

   constructor(private service : SomeService){
     this.obs = this.service.method(param1 ,param2 ,param3);  //Passing param1, param2 and param3 as Inputs on Component2 is not an option 
  }
}
```

**Component 2 TS**

```
export class Component2{
  Input() obs : Observable<any>;
}
```

Obs: Passing param1, param2 and param3 as Inputs is not an option

Hope to have explained my question well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can, but if it's an observable from a service, why dont you inject service directly in component2 ?

Comment: @Soukyone Because component2 should render a paginated list of unknown objects

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an observable, you can do it like a normal object:

Component 1:

```
export class Component1 {

 obs : Observable<any>;      

 constructor(private service : SomeService){
  this.obs = this.service.method(param1 ,param2 ,param3);
 }
}
```

Component 2:

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

@Input() obsFromParent: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.obsFromParent.subscribe((data) => {// do what you want });
 }
}
```

If the observable you pass, is a no-finite observable, think to unsubscribe it, on the ngOnDestroy from Component2.

Comment: The goal is to pass an http request from component 1 to component 2 and **set its params on component 2**

Comment: so, param1, param2 and param3 are on component2, but you want to pass the observable from component1 ? right ?

Comment: Yes, and i dont want param1,2 and 3 to be inputs on component2